# Kendo ui mobile platform: "ios"

Tags: html, cordova, kendo-mobile

I already assigned the  platform: "ios" on my kendo.mobile.Application declaration that goes like this:

`app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), {
            initial    : 'appHome',

            transition : 'none',

            skin       : 'flat',

            loading    : false,

            platform: "ios"
        });`

Here is the HTML part:

```
 <p> iOS B <input data-role="switch" style="border: none; -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);"/> </p>
```

But I still get a none ios looking button

[image]

I would also would like to know how to sold the same situation when it comes to android or Windows development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use skin and platform at the same time.